# View hierarchy not prepared for height constraint added to subview in IB

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to position a custom UIView subclass using auto layout.

The view is initialized in the app's main storyboard, which has a subview with a custom class set in a VC's view. Correspondingly, the custom view has its own header & implementation file for some more fine-tuned programmatic customization down the line but both are blank at this point. This all seems to be working — the debugger shows that the subview's (blank) initWithCoder selector is called and I can get some basic layouts going by adding alignment constraints to the superview...assuming they are dual relation layouts (e.g. First Item RELATED BY Second Item).

The problem arises when I use IB to add a height constraint to the view. App crashes upon launch:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x9339140 V:[IconButton:0x9339c20(50)]>
When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

I've been using auto layout in other use cases for a while and am quite familiar with the more common ambiguous and/or conflicting layouts, but this is a much rarer error that doesn't seem to be related (IB doesn't detect any conflicts)

Comment: The error message means that the constraint that was added to the superview of the view is not a subview of it's superview, if that makes any sense. Hopefully I didn't confuse you even more.

Comment: Use [UIView recursiveDescription] to check that each of the views you are expecting are subviews of the correct superviews. Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION34